# readelf error: not an elf file, wrong magic bytes at the start

Tags: elf, readelf

I am trying to learn and use Elfreader by compiling a simple hello world program to a elf file as-

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

The file compiles correctly and runs perfect.
But when I try to run ReadElf on it by

```
readelf -h test
```

it returns

```
readelf: Error: Not and ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
```

What do you think I am doing wrong, or is there a problem with my linker script?
Let me know if you need any additional info from me.

Comment: It was pretty dumb question from my part. The answer is pretty straight forward (Or I should say the question did not specify that I was using a Windows-Cygwin environment). 
I was using cygwin on Windows. The executable thus produced was a .exe and not an ELF format file. Obviously readelf returned that error since undertaken file is not a valid ELF.

Answer (score -1):

You can check file format type follow as :

```
$ objdump -t hello.exe
```

hello.exe:     file format pei-i386

Maybe I guess your file is not elf format.